# Meta título e meta description duplicados por causa de filtros de categorias

Tags: html, seo

Estou com um problema com `meta title` e `meta descriptions` duplicados, páginas como essas abaixo, o google está entendendo que são páginas diferentes, o que realmente não é.

```
basedosite.com.br/cintos-e-fivelas/

basedosite.com.br/cintos-e-fivelas/cintos/Cintos?O=OrderByReleaseDateDESC&map=c,c,specificationFilter_47

basedosite.com.br/cintos-e-fivelas/cintos-e-fivelas/cintos/Mulheres?O=OrderByReleaseDateDESC&map=c,c,specificationFilter_48
```

Tem alguma solução para este tipo de problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilize em seu html a **meta cannonical** :

```
 <link rel=”canonical” href=”URL” />
```

Isso ira indicar as serps qual a url principal do conteúdo em seguida efetue redirect com 301 das url erradas para a correta. Aguarde alguns dias (depende muito da taxa de rastreio do motor de pesquisa para o domínio), e verifique no google webmaster tools se foi removido do painel.

Regra de redirecionamento .htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ^cintos-e-fivelas/cintos/Cintos?
O=OrderByReleaseDateDESC&map=c,c,specificationFilter_47$ /cintos-e-fivelas/ 
[L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^cintos-e-fivelas/cintos-e-fivelas/cintos/Mulheres?
O=OrderByReleaseDateDESC&map=c,c,specificationFilter_48$ /cintos-e-fivelas/ 
[L,R=301]
```